# REGEXP_SUBSTR in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have log table:

```
with t as
 (select '16/04/2014  20:17:25 XXX. Xxxxxxx xxx xxx   [SYSTEM_JOBS] xxx [POSTPONE_JOBS] xxx [SYSTEM] xxxx [JOB2]' col
    from dual
 UNION ALL
 select '16/04/2014  20:17:25 XXX. Xxxxxxx   [SYSTEM_JOBS] xxx [POSTPONE_JOBS]' col
    from dual)
select * from t
```

I am trying to extract the CODE between '[' and ']' including [].

My version:

```
select regexp_substr(col, '(\[.*?\])', 1, level) col_substr,
       regexp_replace(regexp_substr(col, '(\[.*?\])', 1, level),
                      '(\[|])',
                      '') col_replace_substr
  from t
CONNECT BY regexp_substr(col, '(\[.*?\])', 1, level) is not null
```

My version work good, but i need get result without function **regexp_replace**, i wanna use one function in my code.
Can I get result only with **REGEXP_SUBSTR**?

Comment: `regexp_substr(col, '\[(.*?)\]', 1, level, '', 1)`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff You should add that as an answer.

Comment: @Eat Å Peach, Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question popped up in the "Related" section and even though its an old question it is still relevant and deserves to be answered.  I'm afraid the original poster is incorrect as his code does not work good but returns invalid results.  His example returns 14 rows, where there are only 6 values surrounded by square brackets.  Here is an example with a regex that allows for when the matched pattern is followed by the end of the line and also shows the row number and match number for proof.  I hope this helps a future searcher:

```
SQL> with t(rownbr, col1) as (
    select 1, '16/04/2014  20:17:25 XXX. Xxxxxxx xxx xxx   [SYSTEM_JOBS] xxx [POSTPONE_JOBS] xxx [SYSTEM] xxxx [JOB2]' from dual
    UNION
    select 2, '16/04/2014  20:17:25 XXX. Xxxxxxx   [SYSTEM_JOBS] xxx [POSTPONE_JOBS]' from dual
   )
   SELECT rownbr, column_value match_number,
          regexp_substr(col1,'(\[.*?\])( |$)', 1, column_value, NULL, 1) col_substr,
          regexp_substr(col1,'\[(.*?)\]( |$)', 1, column_value, NULL, 1) col_replace_substr
     FROM t,
          TABLE(
            CAST(
              MULTISET(SELECT LEVEL
                          FROM dual
                          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(col1, '\[.*?\]')
                      ) AS sys.OdciNumberList
            )
          )
    WHERE regexp_substr(col1,'(\[.*?\])( |$)', 1, column_value, NULL, 1) IS NOT NULL;

    ROWNBR MATCH_NUMBER COL_SUBSTR           COL_REPLACE_SUBSTR
---------- ------------ -------------------- --------------------
         1            1 [SYSTEM_JOBS]        SYSTEM_JOBS
         1            2 [POSTPONE_JOBS]      POSTPONE_JOBS
         1            3 [SYSTEM]             SYSTEM
         1            4 [JOB2]               JOB2
         2            1 [SYSTEM_JOBS]        SYSTEM_JOBS
         2            2 [POSTPONE_JOBS]      POSTPONE_JOBS

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```